# Bet sizing to get all their chips

Tags: betting-strategy

Hero flops a hidden monster like full house or top trips on a dry board.  Villain may think they are good. Your objective is to get villain to commit as many chips as possible.

A few options:

1. play it slow and hopefully they catch something or decide to bluff
2. over-bet early
   but you don't want them to fold - not typically a good path
3. spread it into 3 evenly sized (edible delicious) bets

How about option 3? How to size 3 evenly sized (as in pot ratio) bets to get all their chips in the pot.

It could play out 3 bets on the flop alone.  Hero raise/bet pot ratio X, villain re-raise the same pot ratio X, and then hero back with that same re-re-raise.  Boom villain is pot committed.

Answer (score 1):

I am a mathematician and ran the numbers out of curiosity and for table strategy.

p = pot
b = bet as fraction of pot - the denominator (number on bottom)

So for a pot of 10 a b of 1 is a full pot bet of 10
A b of 2 is 1/2 the pot for a bet of 5
A b of 5 is 1/5 the pot for a bet of 2

The calculation for chips to commit (stack that you want) in 3 even bets is
3p/b + 6p/b/b + 4p/b/b/b

You are not going to run that at the table so here are some numbers

```
b   stack ratio  
1   13.0
2    3.5
3    1.8
4    1.2
```

With a pot sized bet just 3 times you can stack a 13:1.  That is pot not BB.  If there are 10 BB in the pot that is 130 BB.

If villain only has 3.5:1 stack to pot ratio then no reason to crazy.  If you can get in three 1/2 pot bets and calls you have them stacked.

Any thing less than 2:1 stack to pot ratio then just bet 1/3 the pot and make it attractive.

Anything less than 1.2:1 stack to pot ratio then might as well push as they are pot committed.  Villain should have pushed pre-flop.